# Automatic import/export of React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I have a "Components" component and a "components" folder.

I want all the components in the folder to be automatically imported into "Components" for reuse. "Components.Button"

It's real?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. This can't be done by default, but there is a good npm package for babel https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-wildcard